# Passar dois arrays para uma view no Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Preciso passar dois arrays para uma view, é possivel fazer isso?

Os arrays são criados da seguinte forma:

```
$cliente = ORM::factory('cliente')->where('id', '=', $id)->find();
$usuario = ORM::factory('usuario')->where('codCliente', '=', $cliente->id)->find_all();
```

Preciso passar o array `$cliente` e o array `$usuario` para a minha view, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim:

```
$this->template->cliente = $cliente;
$this->template->usuario = $usuario;
```

Ou assim:

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('sua/view/aqui')
    ->bind('cliente', $cliente)
    ->bind('usuario', $usuario);
```

Neste caso (usando `bind()`) você está referenciando as variáveis em `$this->template->content`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou